# Getting started with Model Sim

Tags: simulator

I'm trying to simulate a simple Combinatorial Circuit in `ModelSim PE Student Edition 10.4a`. But each time, when I try to Simulate the circuit by loading the design from Library Panel. I'm getting this error message

> # Error loading design

Although compilation does not show any error.

Here's the code I'm using

```
module smpl_circuit(A,B,C,x,y);
input A,B,C;
output x,y;
wire e;
and g1(e,A,B);
not g2(y,C);
or g3(x,e,y);
endmodule
```

Not even this code. Which ever code I try, I'm getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error loading design usually happens when Model Sim can't find your file. Setting up a project in Model Sim successfully isn't as obvious as it should, so make sure you follow these steps when creating a file:

1. Press **File** -> **Create Project** -> **Create New File**
2. Input your file name and select your file type (Verilog, in this case). Copy paste your code in this newly generated file.
3. Go to the **project tab** (it should be on the left of your screen now). Right click your file.
4. Press **Compile** -> **Compile Selected**. This should make a green check mark appear under the "status" column in the tab.
5. Now go to the **library tab**.
6. Expand the **"work"** directory.
7. Right click on your file and press **Simulate**.

This should make your project work correctly.

P.S. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mpRF6bAY1g) video shows the process neatly.

Comment: I get it, It was a licensing problem. That's why I was getting this error message.